# Get the userID synchronously or asynchronously (iOS)?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement. Some of the screens are not account based. So the users can view them without login. But when they click the "favorite" button. The user will be asked to login in login page. After login, if the user does login, the previous favorite action should be continued. And if the user did not login, the previous action should be stopped.

So I think this an asynchronously login case. The usual synchronous way can not handle this. So my idea is to pass in a login completion block. Like this:

```
typedef void (^LoginComplete)(NSString *userID);

- (void)getUserIDWithCompletion:(LoginComplete)loginComplete;
```

Am I right? Or how do u guys usually handle this kind of case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, all networking is done asynchronously from the developers perspective, aka, completion closures. This is however a synchronous operation for the user, since they are blocked from viewing the rest of the content until the operation continues.

Either way, your approach is good.

Comment: OK. I got what u mean. But I think for user, it's also a sychronous operation when considerring this from the whole app perspective. Because the user still can dismiss the popped login screen to view others screens. Anyway, thanks. I think I will use a completion closure (callback) for this case. Thanks!